# how to make entry widget in python tkinter give me the text inside it on pressing enter key

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

So, lately, I was making this game on python Tkinter where the computer gives me a random word and I have to type out the words and letters I see in the word give to me, so the problem here is that, "ans"
is an entry widget and I want it to work like once I am done typing the word or letter I see in the given word I should press the enter key and when I press the enter key the computer should see whatever is written inside the widget and take it inside a variable so that I can type that variable as the text of the label present on the right side (a1-a18) of the screen, and on pressing enter it should do all that and also delete everything that was previously written inside the entry widget

```
def word():
    rt = Tk()
    rt.geometry("2445x990+0+0")
    rt.title("the minion game")

    tops = Frame(rt, width =1540, height = 10,bg = "steel blue", relief = SUNKEN)
    tops.pack(side=TOP)

    side = Frame(rt, width = 1540, height = 800, bg = "steel blue", relief = SUNKEN)
    side.pack(side=LEFT)

    sider = Frame(rt, width = 831, height = 800, bg = "steel blue", relief = SUNKEN)
    sider.pack(side=RIGHT)

    words = ["banana", "period", "bottle", "company", "pencil", "fishes"]
    word = random.choice(words)

    lblInfo = Label(tops, font=('arial',30,'bold', 'underline'), text ="   P1                                               Your word is: " + word + "                                                   ", width = 67, justify = "left" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    lblInfo.grid(row=0, column=0)

#left side
    ans = tk.Entry(side,textvariable = name ,bg = "steel blue", font=('arial',15,'bold'),width = 40, insertwidth=4, bd=15, justify = "left").grid(row=3,column=0)

    lblInfo = Label(side, font=('arial',50,'bold'), text = "         Type here", width = 17,justify = "left" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    lblInfo.grid(row=1, column=0)

    lblInfo = Label(side, font=('arial',50,'bold', 'underline'), text = "", width = 9,justify = "left" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    lblInfo.grid(row=2, column=0)

    lblInfo = Label(side, font=('arial',50,'bold', 'underline'), text = "", width = 9,height = 5,justify = "left" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    lblInfo.grid(row=4, column=0)

    lblInfo = Label(side, font=('arial',50,'bold', 'underline'), text = "", width = 9,height = 3,justify = "left" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    lblInfo.grid(row=0, column=0)

    lblInfo = Label(side, font=('arial',5,'bold', 'underline'), text = "", width = 1,height = 35,justify = "left" , bg = "black", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    lblInfo.grid(row=0, column=1)

    lblInfo = Label(side, font=('arial',5,'bold', 'underline'), text = "", width = 1,height = 100,justify = "left" , bg = "black", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    lblInfo.grid(row=4, column=1)

    lblInfo = Label(side, font=('arial',5,'bold', 'underline'), text = "", width = 1,height = 13,justify = "left" , bg = "black", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    lblInfo.grid(row=3, column=1)

    lblInfo = Label(side, font=('arial',5,'bold', 'underline'), text = "", width = 1,height = 13,justify = "left" , bg = "black", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    lblInfo.grid(row=1, column=1)

    lblInfo = Label(side, font=('arial',5,'bold', 'underline'), text = "", width = 1,height = 15,justify = "left" , bg = "black", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    lblInfo.grid(row=2, column=1)

#right side
    lblInfo = Label(sider, font=('arial',30,'bold', 'underline'), text = "", width = 1,height = 2,justify = "left" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    lblInfo.grid(row=0, column=0)

    lblInfo = Label(sider, font=('arial',35,'bold'), text = "your words:", width = 35,justify = "right" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    lblInfo.grid(row=1, column=0)

    a1 = Label(sider, font=('arial',15,'bold'), text = "a1", width = 35,justify = "right" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    a1.grid(row=2, column=0)

    a2 = Label(sider, font=('arial',15,'bold'), text = "a4", width = 35,justify = "right" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    a2.grid(row=3, column=0)

    a3 = Label(sider, font=('arial',15,'bold'), text = "a3", width = 35,justify = "right" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    a3.grid(row=4, column=0)

    a4 = Label(sider, font=('arial',15,'bold'), text = "a2", width = 35,justify = "right" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    a4.grid(row=5, column=0)

    a5 = Label(sider, font=('arial',15,'bold'), text = "a5", width = 35,justify = "right" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    a5.grid(row=6, column=0)

    a6 = Label(sider, font=('arial',15,'bold'), text = "a6", width = 35,justify = "right" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    a6.grid(row=7, column=0)

    a7 = Label(sider, font=('arial',15,'bold'), text = "a7", width = 35,justify = "right" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    a7.grid(row=8, column=0)

    a8 = Label(sider, font=('arial',15,'bold'), text = "a8", width = 35,justify = "right" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    a8.grid(row=9, column=0)

    a9 = Label(sider, font=('arial',15,'bold'), text = "a9", width = 35,justify = "right" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    a9.grid(row=10, column=0)

    a10 = Label(sider, font=('arial',15,'bold'), text = "a10", width = 35,justify = "right" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    a10.grid(row=11, column=0)

    a11 = Label(sider, font=('arial',15,'bold'), text = "a11", width = 35,justify = "right" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    a11.grid(row=12, column=0)

    a12 = Label(sider, font=('arial',15,'bold'), text = "a12", width = 35,justify = "right" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    a12.grid(row=13, column=0)

    a13 = Label(sider, font=('arial',15,'bold'), text = "a13", width = 35,justify = "right" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    a13.grid(row=14, column=0)

    a14 = Label(sider, font=('arial',15,'bold'), text = "a10", width = 35,justify = "right" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    a14.grid(row=15, column=0)

    a15 = Label(sider, font=('arial',15,'bold'), text = "a11", width = 35,justify = "right" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    a15.grid(row=16, column=0)

    a16 = Label(sider, font=('arial',15,'bold'), text = "a12", width = 35,justify = "right" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    a16.grid(row=17, column=0)

    a17 = Label(sider, font=('arial',15,'bold'), text = "a13", width = 35,justify = "right" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    a17.grid(row=18, column=0)

    a18 = Label(sider, font=('arial',15,'bold'), text = "a13", width = 35,justify = "right" , bg = "steel blue", bd = 1, anchor = 'w')
    a18.grid(row=19, column=0)
```

if someone has any idea how I can do that and where to add it inside this code pls do tell me.

Thankyou

Comment: First of all `ans = tk.Entry(...).grid(...)` doesn't do what you think it does. Is saves whatever `.grid` returns into `ans` instead of the actual `tkinter.Entry` widget. So change it to `ans = tk.Entry(...)` and `ans.grid(...)`. Also you should add `global ans` at the start of that function and later can just call `ans.get()`

Comment: You could use: `widget.bind('<Return>', func)`

Comment: @TheLizzard I am new to tkinter and I was just learning about it, so it would be really helpfull if you could explain it in a bit more detailed way..

Comment: @vatsal Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name). Also that's just how python works. It isn't anything special with tkinter.

Comment: when i run this ans.bind `("<Return>", print(print_entry))` it gives me this error 

`Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Vatsa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 1699, in call return self.func(*args) File "C:\Users\Vatsa\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\all main py files\The Minion game.py", line 44, in word ans.bind("<Return>", print(print_entry)) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'`

Comment: @vatsal First of all you can get that error only if you didn't split the `ans = tk.Entry(...).grid(...)` into `ans = tk.Entry(...)` and `ans.grid(...)`. Second of all you have to pass in a function so use `ans.bind("<Return>", lambda event: print(ans.get()))`

Comment: `def print_entry(event):
    print(ans.get())
    ans.delete(0,END)`

i split it like u told now it does not give the error but on running instead of printing what I type it prints this `<function print_entry at 0x0000023AAE469620>`

and also it does not delete the thing written in the widget

Comment: @vatsal Did you change the `ans.bind("<Return>", print(print_entry))` into `ans.bind("<Return>", lambda event: print(print_entry))`?

Comment: yes it still prints the same thing  `print_entry at 0x0000023AAE469620>` and doesn't erase the thing written In the widget

Comment: so what should i do now?? i changed it like you have told me to but it still doesn't print the thing written inside the widget

Comment: @vatsal You have like three answer to look at, also I suggest looking at tutorials, since it would really help You if You learned how to create widgets in a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
def word():
    global ans
    ...
    ans = Entry(side, ...)
    ans.grid(...)
    ans.bind("<Return>", enter_pressed)
    ...

def enter_pressed(event):
    print(ans.get())
    ans.delete(0, "end")
```

Also I suggest that you look at some programming tutorials and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name).

Comment: thanks for the help and sure i will look at some tutorials'

Comment: Why not `event.widget.get()`. But that would make it similar to the answer below, but it would remove `global`.

Comment: @CoolCloud I am trying to teach OP the basics of how python works because most of the time people start with functional programming and for that you need to know how global variables work. But it isn't a bad idea. Feel free to edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To bind the return/enter key, use `entry.bind("<Return>", func)`:

```
from tkinter import *

class UI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.entry = Entry(root)
        # Bind the return key
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.func)
        self.entry.pack()

    def func(self, event):
        print(self.entry.get())


root = Tk()
UI()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please don't use classes. I don't think OP knows about object oriented programming yet. Try using a global variable instead.

Comment: @TheLizzard I think it can be done without the use of global variables by using `StringVar()`

Comment: @Matiiss I don't think OP is very familiar with `StringVar` and introducing too many concepts at the same time can be counterproductive.

Comment: Yes, but using global varibles isn't good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of doing this without the use of `global` (since I have heard they are "evil"):

```py
from tkinter import Entry, Tk


def func(event):
    print(event.widget.get())
    event.widget.delete(0, 'end')


def main():
    root = Tk()

    entry = Entry(root)
    entry.pack()
    entry.bind('<Return>', func)

    root.mainloop()


main()
```

Comment: You don't need the lambda. The event object has a reference to the entry widget. You can use `event.widget.get()` inside your function.

Comment: @BryanOakley oh, thanks for the reminder, completely forgot about that, edited the code now